# Using a "with" contextmanager with pysqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, contextmanager, pysqlite

I'm trying to use the "with" contextmanager using [pysqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

```
>>> with conn.cursor() as db:
  res = db.execute("SELECT * FROM Publishers LIMIT 5;").fetchall()

... ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __enter__
```

I see that the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods are not defined, so a `with` contextmanager won't be available.

I also understand from the pysqlite documentation that the sqlite3 is a little quirky with respect to connections.  In general, I would prefer use the context manager with python DB APIs per idiomatic python.

Does this suggest that I /should not/ try overloading and achieving a context manager?  That there's something in the sqlite3 bindings that make this not advisable or not idiomatic?

Does this mean proper usage would be instantiating my cursor only one time (`db = conn.cursor()`) as a global and calling it (`db.execute(query,params)`) in each of my functions?  Or that I must re-instantiate, call, and close the db in every function (`db = conn.cursor(); db.query(query,params); db.close()` and do so verbosely, lacking the context manager?

Comment: is there a reason you’re not using sqlite from the stdlib?

Comment: also your questions depend on your use case, is your process idempotent? if not you’ll probably want one instance of a cursor so you can roll everything back and vice versa

Comment: @aws_apprentice, yes, I'm using the fts5 and json modules, which you have to build yourself.  So, my import ends up as from `pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3` from http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-the-sqlite-json1-and-fts5-extensions-with-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager), you use the **connection** as the context manager (`with conn as db:`), not the **cursor to the connection** (<strike>`with conn.cursor() as db:`</strike>):

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.execute("create table person (id integer primary key, firstname varchar unique)")

# Successful, con.commit() is called automatically afterwards
with con:
    con.execute("insert into person(firstname) values (?)", ("Joe",))

# con.rollback() is called after the with block finishes with an exception, the
# exception is still raised and must be caught
try:
    with con:
        con.execute("insert into person(firstname) values (?)", ("Joe",))
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    print "couldn't add Joe twice"
```